# "Cannot find module 'HTML'" getting this error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

I created a small html form with nodesjs as backend but cannot submit form getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
Require stack:
- D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\view.js
- D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\index.js
- D:\web\smallmongoproject\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at new View (D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at D:\web\smallmongoproject\app.js:41:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\web\smallmongoproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
```

After submitting form it is supposed to entry the data in mongodb and render the same form again. but instead i am getting this error after submitting the form so it is rendering for the first time only.

Comment: `npm I html` — Don't install modules you aren't using.

Comment: This sounds like you tried to configure the view engine to be HTML … which isn't a template language so makes no sense … but you failed to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running `npm i html` in your shell. This should install the html module dependency.

Comment: After installing i am getting this problem: "Error: Module "html" does not provide a view engine."

Comment: That module is an "HTML pretty printer CLI utility". It doesn't make any sense to install it as a dependency for an Express.js project.